# Is there a vagrant cli way of completely rebuilding a vagrant box while saving the old one?

Tags: vagrant

I tried

```
vagrant snapshot push
vagrant destroy
vagrant snapshot pop
```

But of course the VM is gone so that won't work. The problem is that if I want to debug provisioning from scratch then I don't want to nuke my whole dev setup each time. As a workaround I can redefine my Vagrant file into a multi-machine setup probably and make abuse that to get new boxes.

Is there vagrant cli way of saving and restoring my setup?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you need to create your own box with predefined setup.
You may try [package](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/package.html) for this.

Comment: I suppose that could work for exporting, but then to import wouldn't I need to `vagrant destroy`, change `config.vm.box`, `vagrant up`, change  the `config.vm.box` value back to revert everything? It would probably be easier to just keep a 2nd machine that doesn't autostart, call it "bootstrap" and then start and destroy it only when I want to test provisioning.